# Rails Error - cannot load such file -- aws-sdk (You may need to install the aws-sdk gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a RoR app with image upload through paperclip and amazon s3.  Everything was working fine until I decided to change the routes from myapp.com/id to myapp.com/model-name.  Now I get the following error: `LoadError cannot load such file -- aws-sdk (You may need to install the aws-sdk gem)`.  These changes involved changing the model, the controller, and the db.

Model:

```
class Major < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :glance, :name, :image

  # Validations
  validates :glance, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates_attachment :image, content_type: {content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']}, size: { less_than: 5.megabytes }
  validates :slug, uniqueness: true, presence: true

  before_validation :generate_slug

  # Associations
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { 
   profile: "350x350>", 
   similar: '166x134>', 
   thumb: "100x100>" 
  },
    :storage => :s3,
    :bucket => 'major finder'
    :s3_credentials => {
      :access_key_id => 'my_key_id',
      :secret_access_key => 'my_secret_access_key'
    },
    :path => "/majors/:attachment/:style/:filename"    

  # make the url path memorable (instead of using the id)
  def to_param
    slug
  end

  def generate_slug
    self.slug ||= name.parameterize
  end 
end
```

Controller:

```
class MajorsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :edit]
  before_filter :find_page, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @majors_recent = Major.order("created_at DESC")
    @majors = Major.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @majors }
    end
  end

  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @major }
    end
  end

  def new
    @major = Major.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @major }
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @major = Major.new(params[:major])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @major.save
        format.html { redirect_to @major, notice: 'Major was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @major, status: :created, location: @major }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @major.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @major.update_attributes(params[:major])
        format.html { redirect_to @major, notice: 'Major was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @major.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @major.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to majors_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

private 
  def find_page
    @major = Major.find_by_slug!(params[:id])
  end
end
```

My database schema looks like this:

```
  create_table "majors", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "glance",             :limit => 255
    t.datetime "created_at",                        :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                        :null => false
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  end
```

Here's my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem 'activeadmin'


group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'sunspot_solr'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.2.2.0'
end
```

I ran `$ rails g migration add_slug_to_majors slug:index` and then `$ rake db:migrate`
Now even though I've removed all the changes I am still getting this error.  I have looked all over and can't find a solution.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If your `Gemfile` includes `aws-sdk-s3` and you're getting this error, it means you need to upgrade your `paperclip` gem version to 6+, when they started supporting the `aws-sdk-s3` gem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is written in error, you need `aws-sdk` gem also in development mode (as you're using it in your model). Simply move `gem 'aws-sdk'` outside the group.

*BTW*: Use the same DB engine in dev and production mode, I have some problems with thet configuration as you have.

Comment: That makes sense!  Thank you!  I can't believe I missed that.  Thank you!!

Comment: What problems do you have with the configuration? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Postgres parse arguments passed to DB in other way than SQLite so in dev all tests pass but production doesn't work.

Comment: the solution is not that obvious see my answer below. Since many items in a larger project are written by other developers the problem I was experiencing required a downgrade into a specific gem

Answer (score 9):

This is actually an *issue* you might experience with managing versions within the *Gemfile*.

In my case it a newer version of *paperclip* causing the **issue**. Downgrading to and older version fixed it for me.

Comment: Happened to me too with version 6.0.0

Comment: I can confirm that problem with paperclip too (manually added as an upgrade for mongoid-paperclip (unmaintained since 4 years ago)), solved only on version 6.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue today (10/5/2021) re-writing an app called FilterTRAK from Rails v4.2.1 to Rails v6.1.4.1.

I was getting the exact error in the subject of this question.

I was unable to downgrade paperclip due to a dependency issue on Mimemagic 0.3.0 which has been YANKED.
Mimemagic 0.3.7 is all that is available and to do that you have to go up to paperclip 5.0; problem is paperclip 5.0 gave the same error.

SOLUTION:
The gem paperclip-aws
I installed that gem specifically like this:

```
gem 'paperclip-aws', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.8'
```

And my application loaded up correctly.