# Aws-sdk gem 'cannot load such file' error on remote server but not locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, aws-sdk

This looks very similar to [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078455/rails-error-cannot-load-such-file-aws-sdk-you-may-need-to-install-the-aws?rq=1) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236847/issue-with-paperclip-s3-in-rails-3-2-5-cannot-load-such-file-aws-sdk?rq=1) but those solutions don't look like they apply here.

I can run my rails app in production mode locally, but on a remote server it fails with a message about the `aws-sdk` gem:

```
A LoadError occurred in images#index:

cannot load such file -- aws-sdk (You may need to install the aws-sdk gem)
app/controllers/images_controller.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in index'
```

`aws-sdk` is being used by `Paperclip 4.2.0`, which as of now only integrates with aws-sdk 1.x (no version 2). `require 'aws-sdk'` is not anywhere in my own code. Offending action code:

```
@images = @viewable.images
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {}
  #line 9:
  format.json {render json: @images, root: false, each_serializer: ImageSerializer}
end
```

What I've investigated so far follows.

#### Remote vs Local configuration

This seems most likely to be the cause. Perhaps some crucial config is not being found by my server such that aws-sdk can't be initialised. Here's how my config works:

S3 is configured according to [this page](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Paperclip-with-Amazon-S3). I followed the tutorial exactly except for a slight change to accommodate multiple production mode servers:

config/application.yml (values loaded to `ENV` by [figaro](https://rubygems.org/gems/figaro/versions/1.1.0)):

```
production:
  s3_bucket: 'mybucket'

development:
  s3_bucket: 'mybucket'
```

config/aws.yml (loaded automatically by aws-sdk):

```
development:
  access_key_id: AK_MY_ID
  secret_access_key: MYSECRET
production:
  access_key_id: AK_MY_ID
  secret_access_key: MYSECRET
```

Excerpt from config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV['s3_bucket']
  }
}
```

As far as I can tell symlinks for each yml file are being created correctly on each deploy:

```
deployer:~/apps/myapp/releases/20150505130826$ ll config/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 deployer deployer    53 May  5 13:08 application.yml -> /home/deployer/apps/myapp/shared/config/application.yml
lrwxrwxrwx  1 deployer deployer    45 May  5 13:08 aws.yml -> /home/deployer/apps/myapp/shared/config/aws.yml
```

Other things I've checked:

#### I doubt this controller is at fault

Other actions and controllers that access the same model also fail, and it fails on the remote server only.

#### Gem installation looks good

I have had no problems with other gems being lost during deployment over several months. There is no output from bundler saying that the install has failed. From capistrano deploy output:

```
 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.1.5@myapp do bundle install --path /home/deployer/apps/myapp/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet as deployer@myapp.com
DEBUG [c43674b8] Command: cd /home/deployer/apps/myapp/releases/20150505130826 && ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.1.5@myapp do bundle install --path /home/deployer/apps/myapp/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
INFO [c43674b8] Finished in 3.582 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

From a shell I can inspect where the gem is installed:

```
~/apps/myapp/releases/20150505130826$ ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.1.5@myapp do bundle show aws-sdk
/home/deployer/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-1.64.0
```

In the rails console:

```
2.1.5 :001 > Gem.loaded_specs['aws-sdk'].full_gem_path
 => "/home/deployer/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-1.64.0"
```

So it seems like Rails *does* know about the gem.

#### AWS credentials look good

Identical credentials work perfectly (in dev mode and in production mode) on my local machine. Credentials also work using s3cmd on the remote server. When I deliberately set them to incorrect values on my local machine, I get Access Denied errors from AWS, not the whole action falling over like this.

Where else can I look for problems?

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the  `gem 'aws-sdk-v1'`.  It was work well for my aws project.